# Are naturals definable from reals using second-order or infinite axioms?

Tags: logic, definition

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/263284/704370), and specifically in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263296/704370), it is explained
that $\mathbb{N}$ is not definable in $\mathbb{R}$ using the language
of ordered fields (using $0$, $1$, $+$, $\cdot$, $<$) with a
first-order formula. In the answer there are some words about second-order
logic, but they're very brief.

So I'm wondering:

> 1. Is it possible to use a second-order formula to define $\mathbb{N}$?
>      What would it look like?
> 2. Is it possible to add an axiom schema in first-order logic (adding,
>      effectively, infinite many axioms) to define $\mathbb{N}$? What would
>      it look like?

(I'm interested in both questions)

The same answer shows that a second-order formula like $$\forall \phi \big[\phi(0)\land\forall x\big(\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi(x+1)\big)\big]$$ defines an *inductive set* (although the formula there uses set notation),
but I don't know if it's enough since it's still necessary to show
that there is a "minimum inductive set", isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb N$ is the set of all $y\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$
\forall\phi\,\big([\phi(0)\land\forall x\,(\phi(x)\to\phi(x+1))]\to\phi(y)\big);
$$
in other words, every inductive set contains $y$.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with second-order logic. Does this formula categorize $\mathbb N$ as a "minimum inductive set"? (With minimum I mean, of course, that is a subset of every inductive set) In FOL usually you prove that such a set exists, that is really a subset of every inductive set and then you denote that set as $\mathbb{N}$ or $\omega$ (depending on the theory). Also, do you have an answer to second question? I'm interested in both of them.

Comment: By the upward Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem, no collection of first-order statements can uniquely (up to isomorphism) characterize $\mathbb N$ (or any other infinite structure).

Comment: @Daniel Showing that the definition works is different from giving the definition itself. This does define $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all inductive sets; properties of this definition (e.g. that said intersection is nonempty) do indeed require verification if we want to use them, but this does define $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.